# It would be fortunate if

Tags: sentence-meaning

Can "It would be fortunate if ..." be used to make a request?

Is it correct to say the following?

> It would be fortunate if you would answer my question.

Comment: That's not something that would normally be said. Actually, to me, that almost sounds more like a veiled threat. (*You would be wise to do what I say, if you know what's good for you . . .*)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a phrase which would be likely to be said by a native speaker.

English sentences tend to have some sort of logic to them. So in this case

> It would be fortunate if ...

Something is literally fortunate if it happens by luck. But answering a question has nothing to do with luck, especially when you are speaking directly to a person. Therefore your sentence is illogical and sounds 'wrong' to an English speaker. The only thing that needs to be answered is whether the object of the sentence *is able and willing* to reply.

A natural way to say it would be:

> I would be grateful if you would answer my question.

Comment: What about "It would be fortunate if you would help with the housework"?

Comment: Same answer. You could say it, but it doesn't sound entirely natural.